# Разместить слой, после слоя с position: absolute

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте, вот задача: После слоя с `position: absolute;` нужно разместить следующий слой, так, чтобы он стоял после предыдущего.

Пример кода:

```css
.full-screen {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <div class="full-screen"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

**Цель**: первый слой должен быть на весь экран, а второй должен идти после него. Эту задачу можно решить несколькими способами.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Если блок должен скроллиться

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
  opacity: .5;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="full-screen"></div>
<div>Тут какой-то контент</div>
```

Comment: Может вы просто внесёте всё в один ответ?

Comment: @Klimenkomud, зачем?

Comment: Ваших два ответа - по сути один, просто для двух случаев. Зачем плодить сообщения? Можно ведь поместить всё в один содержательный ответ.

Comment: @Klimenkomud, на мой взгляд они разные.

Answer (score 2):

## Если блок должен быть оверлеем, а НЕ скроллиться

```css
html, body, section {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.full-screen {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  background: silver;
  opacity: .5;
  pointer-events: none;
}

section {
  overflow: auto;
}

section:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div class="full-screen"></div>
  <div>Тут какой-то контент</div>
</section>
```